# Datagrid not displaying initial values of data source

Tags: wpf

I'm using a WPF Datagrid and set the ItemSource to an ObservableCollection.  If the data in the collection changes the DataGrid shows the latest values.  If the collection values don't change after I set the ItemsSource, and assuming the collection has values other than 0, the DataGrid only displays 0 until the data in the collection changes.  Basically it isn't displaying the initial values in the collection.

I've implemented INotifyPropertyChanged
I've tried DataGrid.Items.Refresh();

Any ideas would be appreciated.

My Error, the values were not being propagated to the collection until the source of the data changed.

Comment: Hard to debug without code...

Comment: ...True, but exposing my application was not an option.  I was just fishing around for anyone that may have had a simalar issue.

Comment: It's ill advised to post a large chunk of code anyway.  Strip your code down to the smallest chunk that reproduces the issue and post that.

Answer (score 0):

My Error, the values were not being propagated to the collection